# Top 10 records from two fields on same MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

Here's a part of my **MySQL** table structure:

```
questionRecID       value   periodMonth     periodYear      practiceID
           16          70            11           2010             475  
           28          33            11           2010             475
           14         226            11           2010             475
```

Question Rec ID 14 is the denominator used to calculate percentages. So, goes like this:

`percent = (70 / 226) * 100`. This gives me the percentage for question of rec ID 16 for Nov 2010.

I need to query the entire table to get the top 10 performing practices across all years and all months stored. 
Either php or SQL is fine with me. I'm really stuck on how to get the data out of this table.

Comment: What have you tried?  I find it odd that `questionRecID = 14` has such a specific purpose.

Comment: i dont understand anything , you do 70 / 226 so what about id = 28 ?

Comment: question 14 is the denominator to calculate the percent of question 16. Like this: q14 - How many patients have Asthma, q16 - How many patients have Asthma classified as persistent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;
CREATE TABLE my_table (questionRecID       INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,value   INT NOT NULL,periodMonth     INT NOT NULL, periodYear      INT NOT NULL, practiceID INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(16          ,70            ,11           ,2010             ,475  ),
(28          ,33            ,11           ,2010             ,475),
(14         ,226            ,11           ,2010             ,475);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+---------------+-------+-------------+------------+------------+
| questionRecID | value | periodMonth | periodYear | practiceID |
+---------------+-------+-------------+------------+------------+
|            14 |   226 |          11 |       2010 |        475 |
|            16 |    70 |          11 |       2010 |        475 |
|            28 |    33 |          11 |       2010 |        475 |
+---------------+-------+-------------+------------+------------+

SELECT x.*
     , x.value/y.value pct 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.practiceid = x.practiceid 
   AND y.questionrecid = 14;
+---------------+-------+-------------+------------+------------+--------+
| questionRecID | value | periodMonth | periodYear | practiceID | pct    |
+---------------+-------+-------------+------------+------------+--------+
|            14 |   226 |          11 |       2010 |        475 | 1.0000 |
|            16 |    70 |          11 |       2010 |        475 | 0.3097 |
|            28 |    33 |          11 |       2010 |        475 | 0.1460 |
+---------------+-------+-------------+------------+------------+--------+
```